# jQuery function does not replace input value after error is alerted and corrected

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

I have a code that validates if the value of an input is a YouTube video URL. It works well until the user corrects his error.

So, imagine you are the user and enter an incorrect URL. The code tells you that the URL is invalid, so you paste another URL that is correct this time. And then you click "Insert".

That's were the problem appears.

The value that appears in the textarea (where the URL is suppose to be inserted) is the first one/previous one that you inserted instead of the correct one.

I've tried it to fix it by modifying the .on('input') function, but when I do so, it stops working completely.

https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/pebjtwrz/169/

```
<textarea id="ECEditor" class="editor-textarea" style="height: 50px;" name="editor-text"></textarea>


        <div class="fonts-box insert-video insert-box">

            <form id="insertForm" class="IFvideo">
                <p style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600;">YouTube video URL:</p>
                <input id="videoURL" placeholder="https://" required name="video-url"/><br>

                <p style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 5px;">Width:</p>
                <input class="numericWidth" id="VIDEOwidth" name="video-width" placeholder="Example: 300, 400, 500" required/><br>

                <p style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; margin-top: 5px;">Height:</p>
                <input class="numericHeight" id="VIDEOheight" name="video-height"placeholder="Example: 300, 400, 500" required/>
            </form>

            <span id='wrapperVIDEO'>
                <input value="Insert" type="button" id="insertVIDEO" class="insertButton"/>
            </span>

            <p class="InvalidSize" style="display:none;">Invalid size</p>
            <p class="InvalidURL" style="display:none;">Invalid URL</p>

        </div>

<script>function NoWrapTags(type,value) {

    var nw = $('.numericWidth').val();
    var nh = $('.numericHeight').val();
    
    var numericWidth = $.isNumeric(nw);
    var numericHeight = $.isNumeric(nh);
    
    //Check if it is a number
    if (numericWidth && numericHeight) {
    
            $('.InvalidSize').hide();

        //Video
        var YTurl = $("#videoURL").val();

        if(YTurl.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=') == false && YTurl.startsWith('https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=') == false) {
            $('.InvalidURL').show();
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ECEditor").value+= "\n"+type+value+"\n";
            $('.InvalidURL').hide();
            $("#insertForm")[0].reset();
        }
            
    } else {
            //Not a number
        $('.InvalidSize').show();
    }
    
}

//Insert video

$('#videoURL', ).on('input', function() {
    var videoC = $(this).val();
    $('#VIDEOwidth').keyup(function() {
        var vwValue = $(this).val();
        $('#VIDEOheight').keyup(function() {
            var vhValue = $(this).val();
            $('#wrapperVIDEO').html('<input value="Insert" type="button" id=\"insertVIDEO\" class=\"insertButton closeInsert\" onclick=\"NoWrapTags(\'[youtube width=' + vwValue + ' height=' + vhValue + ']' + videoC + '\',\'[/youtube]\');"/>');
        });
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Above code is attaching new keyup handlers every time the user input the video. Value of videoC is retrieved from the scope where it was created. Check out what is a closure and lexical scope in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by changing:

```
$('#videoURL', ).on('input', function() {
    var videoC = $(this).val();
    $('#VIDEOwidth').keyup(function() {
        var vwValue = $(this).val();
        $('#VIDEOheight').keyup(function() {
            var vhValue = $(this).val();
            $('#wrapperVIDEO').html('<input value="Insert" type="button" id=\"insertVIDEO\" class=\"insertButton closeInsert\" onclick=\"NoWrapTags(\'[youtube width=' + vwValue + ' height=' + vhValue + ']' + videoC + '\',\'[/youtube]\');"/>');
        });
    });
});
```

to:

```
$('.IFvideo').on('input', function(){

    var videoC = $('#videoURL').val();
    var vwValue = $('#VIDEOwidth').val();
    var vhValue = $('#VIDEOheight').val();

    $('#wrapperVIDEO').html('<input value="Insert" type="button" id=\"insertVIDEO\" class=\"insertButton closeInsert\" onclick=\"NoWrapTags(\'[youtube width=' + vwValue + ' height=' + vhValue + ']' + videoC + '\',\'[/youtube]\');"/>');
});
```